# How common are the following Chinese names: 王朋 & 李友 & 高文中 & 白英愛? My Chinese coursebooks are full of them!

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, names, surnames

**Context:** my Chinese course uses a series of books (called 'Integrated Chinese') in which the following are among the most commonly used names:

- 王朋
- 李友
- 高文中
- 白英愛

It makes me wonder how common these names are in real life? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I saw those names frequently when I first began learning but I've never read that book. I think maybe those names are from the HSK word list

Comment: The HSK lists don't have any names of people in them.

Comment: In that case I don't know what I was doing that those names kept showing up in but I've never seen that book

Comment: I don't actually know, but they combine extremely common family names with characters that beginners learn very early, so they are, in a sense, the easiest names you can think of. When I create learning materials for beginners, I do the same thing. I start with family names that are common and are useful for some reason, then create personal names with characters they need to learn anyway. I would guess (conjecture) that this is what the authors of the textbook did as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a chinese,I have never seen these chinese names in real life .
The common names in china are 张伟，李明，王伟，李伟，张敏 et
[image]

Answer (score 4):

王朋 and 李友 sounds like 'Tom' and 'Joe' in English.

高文中 is not as common as the two above.

白英愛 sounds like a Korean name to me, very fashionable, There is a Korean pop star called 李英爱,  as I know Chinese people do not tend to use 爱 in their name in old tradition.

Answer (score 4):

王朋: super common name

李友: sounds like a regular name, but I never see this given name in real life

高文中: a regular name. 文 is a very common character to put in the middle

白英愛: 爱英 is a very common girl's given name. 英 means flower here. 英爱 could be its less common alteration.

Give you some statistics:

```
王朋：20373人
李友：46353人
高文中：96人
李文中： 635人
白英愛：5人
白爱英：76人
李爱英： 2089人
```

You can use [同名同姓查询](https://www.buyiju.com/cm/tong/) to get an idea of how often a name is used. It is not accurate but can give you some ideas. Some times you may want to change the family name to 李 (or another super big family name) to detect the frequency of a given name.